# Metafor Error: Cannot find the object/variable ('yi') specified for the 'yi' argument

Tags: r, variables, metafor

Having previously used RevMan software for meta-analysis (which is dialogue box driven), I am now learning how to undertake one in R metafor (using RStudio).

I have run escalc on my data set to generate logRR and variance for the yi and vi variables, which I can see in the console screen.

I then try to fit random-effects model using the rma.uni metfor function, but then get the error code in the title of this message. When I try exists("yi") the response is FALSE (vi is TRUE).
[Screenshot of the error in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp5SE.png)

I have tried to replicate this using the metadat dat.bcg data set too using the escalc and rma.uni code on https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/ (where everything looks to have worked OK) but get the same error code.

I have also tried running the dat.bcg data and code directly in R (4.2.2) and get the same error there too.

Is there something I am doing/not doing please?

I have looked online but most solutions point to possible typos in the code, or the variable not being labelled/labelled correctly, which it looks like it is in the console panel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning what `escalc()` returns to any object. Follow along the examples exactly, including things like `dat <- escalc(...)` and it will work.